How to delimit text stored in variable to create a dataframe in python?
I have parsed a pdf file using ai models and got parsed markdown results which is saved in a variable doc_parsed. Printing below its sample contents by code print(doc_parsed[2].text[:1000])
# Details

|Name|Mr. XYZ|
|---|---|
|Age/Sex|XX YRS/X|
|Id.|01x40xxxxx|
|Refered By|Self|
|Collection On|xx/Aug/20xx 0x:x0AM|
|Collected By|xxxxxxx|
|Sample Rec. On|xx/Aug/20xx xx:x0 AM|
|Collection Mode|HOME COLLECTION|
|Reporting On|xx/Aug/20xx 0x:xx PM|
|BarCode|xxxxxx|

# Test Results

|Test Name|Result|Biological Ref. Int.|Unit|
|---|---|---|---|
|Electrolyte Profile, Serum| | | |
|SODIUM (Na+)|136.2|136 - 145|mmol/L|
|POTASSIUM (K+)|4.23|3.5 - 5.5|mmol/L|
|CHLORIDE(Cl-)|106.24|98.0 - 107|mmol/L|
|TOTAL CALCIUM (Ca)|9.00|8.6-10.2|mg/dL|
|IONIZED CALCIUM|4.52|4.4 - 5.4|mg/dl|
|NON-IONIZED CALCIUM|4.49|4.4 - 5.4|mg/dl|
|pH.(Method : ISE Direct)|7.39|7.35 - 7.45| |

ISSUE: I have tried several ways to split this into columns of dataframe with delimeter as | by using pd.read_csv() & pd.read_table() but none worked.
import pandas as pd
import io

pd.read_table(doc_parsed[2].text[:1000], sep="|")


ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'llama_index.core.schema.Document'>

import io 

input_text = io.StringIO(print(doc_parsed[2].text[:1000]))

pd.read_csv(input_text,header=None, delimiter="|", 
            usecols = ["Parameter Name", "Result","Unit","Reference Range"])   


EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

pd.read_csv(input_text,header=None, delimiter="|")   


EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Appreciate any help here.

Your main error (wich all 3 current answers below are overlooking) is that print returns None, not the string it prints. So, the first thing you need to do, is change input_text = io.StringIO(print(doc_parsed[2].text[:1000])) to input_text = io.StringIO(doc_parsed[2].text[:1000]).

Yes this was my major mistake and you pointed out correctly. I was able to correct this after some investigation. Wish I saw 'ur reply earlier. And you are the only one to correctly pin point the issue. This was actually the only problem why I was getting error.

This issue might be due to the markdown not being perfectly formatted or extra characters that pandas doesn't handle well by default.
Potential Solution
You can try the following approach:
input_text = io.StringIO(sample_text)

df = pd.read_csv(input_text, sep="|", skipinitialspace=True)

df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]

Using this method, I was able to successfully parse the markdown into a DataFrame.

I hope this gives you a clean DataFrame with your data nicely organized into columns.

Well in your example you have used partial text data so its working but when I try this on whole set of text then it doesn't work. So to make this work on my complete sample text I had to add ,skiprows=11 to pd.read_csv(). Thanks alot for demonstrating the complete code. That really helped me alot to figure out. Appreciate your help.

There is still an issue with this as the text I have in print(doc_parsed[2].text[:1000]) is NoneType and not string. So this works when you use this inside quotes but not directly from variable

Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like code formatting.

A possible solution:
pd.read_csv(input_text, sep=r'|', engine='python')


Getting error: EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

It works fine on my side with: |Name|Mr. XYZ| |---|---| |Age/Sex|XX YRS/X| |Id.|01x40xxxxx| |Refered By|Self| |Collection On|xx/Aug/20xx 0x:x0AM| |Collected By|xxxxxxx| |Sample Rec. On|xx/Aug/20xx xx:x0 AM| |Collection Mode|HOME COLLECTION| |Reporting On|xx/Aug/20xx 0x:xx PM| |BarCode|xxxxxx|

Is this the input_text = io.StringIO(print(doc_parsed[2].text[:1000])) used ? With this input text  pd.read_csv(input_text, sep=r'|', engine='python') its still giving me the same error

I think input_text that you were using is string type and for me doc_parsed[2].text[:1000] is NoneType which then on applying input_text = io.StringIO(sample_text) becomes _io.StringIO but not string type. So I am still facing issues.

Glad, someone else has meanwhile brought a solution to your problem!

actually 'ur answer is also correct. Issue was I was using print() to break lines \n as form of input data. print() returns NoneType datatype where as you were using direct string to input data. This is why read_csv() wasnt able to get data in my case but it was in 'ur case. Thanks for the help though. Appreciate your effort & time.

markdown tables are annoying but the read_csv should have worked this worked for me on your data
table_data = StringIO(markdown_table)
df = pd.read_csv(table_string, sep="|", skipinitialspace=True, header=0)
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, -1]], axis=1) #this is extra columns from the markdown conversion
print(df)

header =0  basically tells pandas the first row is your column names
skipinitialspace=True
trim the string after delimiter so you get clean values

I have tried this input_text = io.StringIO(print(doc_parsed[2].text[:1000])) df = pd.read_csv(input_text, sep="|", skipinitialspace=True, header=0) but I am still getting the error: EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

is doc_parsed the whole document? what's doc_parsed[2], I assumed it was a list with just the tables no?

yes doc_parsed is whole document as this pdf has multiple pages.. 18 i guess. so doc_parsed[2] represents 3rd page.

you need to delimit the document and chunks of the string that contain only the markdown tables.  if those comments delimit the tables just regex the # with text and new line something like

matches = pattern.findall(text)```

I think this approach will be very useful. Will try this one. Thanks alot !!!
